# Is there an equivalent to the camera 2 API method camera.autoFocus() in the camera API?

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, ip-camera

In first camera i have such method

```
private void takePicture()
{
    camera.autoFocus(new Camera.AutoFocusCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onAutoFocus(boolean success, Camera camera) {
            camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, pictureCallback_RAW, pictureCallback_JPEG);
        }
    });
}
```

And it is convinient , when user take a picture , app is trying focused and than take a picture...

Question is : how a can implement in camera2API some callback or another way to wait until camera take a focus and that take a picture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [this](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic) sample project from Google (or just [Camera2BasicFragment](https://developer.android.com/samples/Camera2Basic/src/com.example.android.camera2basic/Camera2BasicFragment.html)). In general You should request focus, than determine "focus lock" state in `CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback` than capture image and finally request for unlock focus.

Comment: Maybe you know how to set up this mode `CONTROL_SCENE_MODE_ACTION` ? As far as i understand i have to set it in capture request, but maybe you know where exactly? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please look my answer for [that](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40259844/6950238) your question.